# Distribute <li> elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

I want to position list elements inside a bordered div, so they will go "all the way" from right to left, and to take exactly 960px width, but for some reason I can't space between them to catch all the 960px.

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">

        <ul>
            <li class="menu red">1</li>
            <li class="menu blue">2</li>
            <li class="menu yellow">3</li>
            <li class="menu yellow">4</li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuvalsab/MvaeF/

Comment: You can use `<ul class="menu">` rather than giving each `li` that class.

Comment: I know, but originally the code is a little bit different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` technique.  This way, you don't have to define a width on your items.

```
div.wrapper {
  width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  border:5px solid black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li.menu {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 55px 0 0 0;
  border: 8px solid;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MvaeF/4/)**

Comment: This is a nice solution, but right now if I change the text inside the cell, the width is unequal to the other cells...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove default paddings on ul and possibly margins on li's.

```
ul {
    border:5px solid black;
    margin:0;
}
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/MvaeF/2/

Answer (score 0):

First of all... you need to check your match.
960 - UL 5px Padding (5 x 2 = 10) = 950 for the LIs.

That leaves you with 950.
Divided by 4, and you have 237.5 each.

Now, you have 8px border... so 4 x 2 = 16. 
237 - 16 = 221px wide for the LI.
Note, you have it at 200px not 221... so that is some of the space issue you're seeing.

The other issue, natively, the browser gives UL and LIs Margin, different amounts for different browsers. If you are not normalizing, then you have to manually.

```
ul, li {margin:0px; padding:0px; }
```

That will ensure that doesn't interfere with your math.
I think you just edited it.

Regardless... use the 0 padding and 0 margin.
Then make sure your math is solid.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't mentioned I used Reset CSS and * box-sizing (in order to simplify the problem...), and so it was unnecessary to do the math. What I can't still figure out is why I have the padding from "user agent stylesheet" when reset.css is active...